# C phone book program: how to exit avoid infinite loop and how to return to the switch statement menu

Tags: c, switch-statement, infinite-loop

I have a simple phone book written in C that saves input info to a text file on my pc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void validateName(char name[], FILE *fptr);
void validateID(char id[], FILE *fptr);
void validateScore(int score, FILE *fptr);
void addContact(char name[], char id[], int score, FILE *fptr);
void printContact(FILE *fptr);
void printAll();

int main()
{
    char name[30], id[10];
    int score;
    int i;

   FILE *fptr;
   fptr = fopen("C:\\c\\program.txt","w");

   if(fptr == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error!");   
      exit(1);             
   }
    else {  

        bool flag = true;
        do{
            printf("\n1. Press 1 to display record\n"
                   "2. Press 0 to add a new contact\n"
                   "3. Press -1 to display all records\n\n");

            int option;
            scanf("%d", &option);
            switch(option) {
                case 1:
                    printContact(fptr);
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    addContact(name, id, score, fptr);
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                case -1:
                    printAll();
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("wrong choice, try again\n\n");             
            }       

        } while(flag);  

    fclose(fptr);
    return(0);
    }   
}

void validateName(char name[], FILE *fptr){

    bool flag = true;

    while(flag){
        fgets(name, 30, stdin);
        if ((strlen(name) < 3) || (strlen(name) > 20)) {
                printf("error\nplease enter name again: ");
        } else {
            flag = false;
        }       
    }   
}

void validateID(char id[], FILE *fptr){

    bool flag = true;
    while(flag) {
         if (!isalpha(id[0])){
            printf("enter a letter as first char\n");  
        }
         else if(strlen(id) > 10) {
            printf("error too much numbers \n");
        } else {
             flag = false;
         }
    }
}

void validateScore(int score, FILE *fptr) {

        if(score >= 0 && score <= 100) {
            fprintf(fptr, "SCORE: %d\n", score);
            } else {
                printf("invalid input");

                (exit(1));
            }
}

void addContact(char name[], char id[], int score, FILE *fptr) {

    //first name 
    printf("Enter name: ");    
    scanf("%s", name);
    validateName(name, fptr);
    fprintf(fptr,"NAME: %s \n", name);  

     //id   
    printf("Enter id: ");
    scanf("%s", id);
    validateID(id, fptr);
    fprintf(fptr,"STUDENT NO: %s\n", id);

    //score      
    printf("enter score: ");
    scanf("%d", &score);
    validateScore(score, fptr);
}

void printContact(FILE *fptr) {

    int c;
    char contacts[50];

   while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
       fscanf(fptr, "%s", &contacts);

       for(int i = 50; i < 50; i++){
           printf("%s", &contacts);
       }
   }




}

void printAll() {

}
```

my first issue is within the validateID function:
I keep getting into an infinite loop when I try to validate the first condition, which is to make sure the first index is a character.

My second issue is, when the I enter name, student id and score, the program finishes and I don't return to the menu switch statement to select other options?

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of having functions like `void validateXXX` is in my opinion wrong. Compare it to `isalpha` which is similar to a validation. `isalpha` returns an `int` so that you can use it for checking. Your validation functions should probably do the same. So instead of:

```
void validateID(char id[], FILE *fptr){

    bool flag = true;
    while(flag) {
         if (!isalpha(id[0])){
            printf("enter a letter as first char\n");  
        }
         else if(strlen(id) > 10) {
            printf("error too much numbers \n");
        } else {
             flag = false;
         }
    }
}
```

the function could be:

```
int validateID(char id[]){
    if (!isalpha(id[0])){
            printf("enter a letter as first char\n");  
            return 0;
    }    
    if(strlen(id) > 10) {
            printf("error too much numbers \n");
            return 0;
    }    
    return 1;
}
```

and then you could use it like:

```
do {
    scanf("%s", id);    // See below !!!!
} while(!validateID(id));
```

so that you keep reading until a valid ID has been entered.

Next:

**Never** use `scanf("%s", ...)` - **Never**

There is no check for the length of the input so the user can input some text being too long to be stored in the buffer you provide (e.g. `id`). That will be catastrophic for your program as it would write outside array boundary. Your program may crash or do all sorts of strange things.

You should use `fgets` for reading user input. It is much easier and much more secure.

For your main-loop:

Yes, of cause it will terminate as you set `flag` to false in all `case`s in the `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

For `validateID()`, you aren't changing anything within the while loop that would cause termination. You're always checking `id[0]` or `strlen(id)`, but not changing anything about `id` or how you're checking it. If `id[0]` isn't alphanumeric, you'll just loop on that forever. Or, if it is alphanumeric but `strlen(id)` is <= 10, you'll loop on that forever. What exactly are you looping on here?

Your program terminates after a single menu selection because all selections set `flag` to false and it's never re-initialized to `true` - so the `while` loop terminates and your program ends.

Comment: I am looping if the first character is non-alphanumeric AND if there is less than 9 numbers following the first letter. so if those conditions are not met, the loop should display an error and ask the user to reenter a letter or reenter a valid amount of numbers

Comment: how would i re-initialize the flag in the switch statement?

Comment: You need to tell the computer to do what you want it to do. Your design does not lend itself well to do what you want it to do - I've pointed out why your program doesn't work, it's up to you as the programmer to figure out how to fix that, since it's a design issue as opposed to a specific bug one.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the declaration for isalpha() function.

> int isalpha(int c);

This function returns a non-zero value if c is an alphabet, else it returns 0. Your while will always have a true condition maintained. its entering one of the two cases above right? So once it leaves, make sure you return false or 0 to the while so that it comes out. Now it is up to you how u modify this.